# Inform AngularJS about file upload with Django

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

For my webpage I use Django 1.9 for the server-side and AngularJs for some client-side tasks (validation etc).
Also for the CSS I use Bootstrap (and the Angular-Ui).

Now I created the forms I need in Django which inserts them on the actual page. Amongst others, I have an input field of type file which lets the user upload a file.

When the user has chosen a file, I would like to do some checks in AngularJs. The problem is: I have no clue how I can get some kind of callback from Django to know that the upload-file window was closed.
My current solution involves a plain javascript function which is bound to the upload field and calls an AngularJs function, but this does not work properly.

So in my forms.py it looks like that:

```
class UploadForm(forms.Form):
    fa_file = forms.FileField(label='Select a Fasta file',
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'file'})
```

The part of the html page where this field is inserted looks like that:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <input type="text" id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" disabled="disabled"/>
    <div class="file-upload btn btn-sm btn-primary">
        <span>Upload</span>
        {{ form.fa_file }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The javascript function which is bound to the file-upload field is:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("id_fa_file").onchange = function () {
        document.getElementById("uploadFile").value = this.value;
        angular.element(this).scope().changeFaFileValue(this.value);
    };
</script>
```

This on change method is executed whenever the user finishes choosing a file. Essentially this is the behavior I want to achieve and the AngularJS function of my controller 'changeFaFileValue' is executed as well.
But it seems that the execution happens in its own scope. I can tell because I have a watcher in my AngularJS controller for a variable which is changed in 'changeFaFileValue' and this watcher is not triggered when the function is called via this plain Javascript on change function.
But if I call the 'changeFaFileValue' from somewhere in my controller, the watcher executes as expected.

The methods in the controller look like this:

```
$scope.$watch('allow_submit', function(){
   console.log("IT WORKED.");
});

$scope.changeFaFileValue = function(newPath){
    $scope.fa_file_js = newPath;
    $scope.allow_submit = !$scope.allow_submit;
}
```

I think I am missing something important here.
Can you please tell me what would be the correct way to achieve the desired behavior? Is my approach correct at all?

Comment: I think a better approach would be to create the form in  angular and pass the upload to django via an angular resource